# Apache Nifi RedisConnectionPoolService doesnt allow to set username (only password)

Tags: redis, apache-nifi

I am trying to access Redis from Apache Nifi using RedisConnectionPoolService 1.11.3
But the controller does not allow to setup username
Only password field is available..
This gives me an err:

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair
```

Could anyone know the way how to access Redis from Nifi?
I am trying to setup lookup using FetchDistributedMapCache processor.
thank you for advice

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We resolved the problem by implementing REDIS Proxy
the proxy translates password field in format "username|password" to username and password